# Can anybody identify an appropriate radio for this game?

Tags: united-states, transmitter, fox-hunt

Complete radio ignoramous here. I've been playing a game called [The Blackout Club](https://store.steampowered.com/app/599080/The_Blackout_Club/), and I'd quite like to make a 3D model of a radio set for it.

The game is set around 2007 and, as in the picture below, features young teenagers (13-17 years old) monitoring the communications of a sinister conspiracy which uses radio to send commands to their field agents.

[image: One of the tutorial texts from the game]

It would be nice if my 3D model fit the tone / period of the game as much as possible - and so I'm turning to you, the specialists! Can anybody suggest a suitable make and model for me? Something that would be suitable for a dispatcher at their home base?

I was looking at military radios earlier, but I figure they'd probably be encrypted... this needs to be something that an average person could use, that could be intercepted by a teenager.

Thank you reading my odd request!

--Rev

Comment: Are the adults walking around while radio'ing, or do they sit in a car, or do they have something like an "adult police station" where they have someone sitting on a dedicated desk doing comms?

Comment: @ Marcus Müller - No such location or visual has been demonstrated in the game, but audio cues certainly suggest as much.

@ Chris K8NVH - Sorry, I don't understand the phrase "please as in a forum such as history" - are you telling me to go to a random history forum or is there one in particular that you would reccomend? I'll ABSOLUTELY look at the links you sent me.

The game is set in America - here's the trailer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MKzd6YpBBcY

Thanks again!

Comment: You are on the money, Chris. I can see that this request is on the outer bounds of what's considered useful content for this site, but I thought I should take a shot! =D Thank you for your advice - I will replicate the question above on history.stackexchange.com

Comment: The replicated question on history.stackexchange.com : https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/51473/can-anybody-identify-an-appropriate-radio-for-this-game

Comment: @ChrisK8NVH - Sorry, which group? I'm a little confused by your comment.

Comment: @ChrisK8NVH Thank you for your recommendation! In case this is vaguely entertaining, I've also been asked to move on from the history.stackexchange.com site. Where will this question be considered suitable? =D https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/51473/can-anybody-identify-an-appropriate-radio-for-this-game?noredirect=1#comment148064_51473

Comment: @ReverendSpeed Sadly, I do not think your question is applicable anywhere in SE mostly because there is no "1 correct answer" and the best you can hope for is a useful opinion (something SE tries to stay away from; some people have strong opinions).  The Kenwood TS-940S and TS-950S both fit what you are looking for.  And you can find far more by just googling "classic transceivers".  Good luck!  (my comments will self-destruct shortly)

Comment: @ChrisK8NVH, you're a champion, you will be remembered. (Good point with SE format). I'll take your model suggestions.